# Is it possible to hook into SBT's source change analyzer?

Tags: scala, sbt

I want to change `publishLocal` so that it only publishes if there is a source code change, similar to what happens with `~compile`. I was thinking about doing this by hooking into the source code analyzer if that's possible - is it?

Thanks!

Comment: You can override the `compile` task and/or what are the watched sources.